# can I turn on the optimizer for some files in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have 2-3 .cpp files in my application (>300 files) which are dead-slow in debug mode. When I run it in release mode (ie with optimizer on -O2 mode), then the speed is good. 80% of the time my code is spent inside these 3 files.

Now, these particular files are well tested, and I don't really ever need to step into this code to debug it. So, I need the speed, and don't care about whether they'll show messed up when I *step in*.

Is there a way I can turn on the optimiser for some particular files, but keep it off for the rest ?

Comment: You can turn it on/off with `#pragma optimize`. [See here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Have you considered building release with debug info? Depending on what you're trying to do that may be a good option for your whole project.

Comment: @JonathanMee yes, but it's hard to debug with all lines moved about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the "Solution explorer", right click on particular file in the opened dialog choose "C++/Optimization" select Disable

Answer (score 2):

You can split your project to libraries and optimize only some of them